# How to read in JetBrains IDE configuration file that someone has shared (by saving with 'Store as project file' in 'Run/Debug Configurations')

Tags: configuration, jetbrains-ide

**JetBrains IDEs** like IntelliJ have **Run/Debug Configurations**.

When creating or modifying a configuration, you can select a **checkbox** with a label "**Store as project file**".

Once this file is shared with someone, how can they import it into their **Run/Debug Configurations**?

Using IntelliJ version 2022.2.3.

Comment: The IDE will save the file with the run configuration settings so you can share it with other team members. The default location is `.idea/runConfigurations`. Just copy such files and re-open the project (not sure if it's really needed). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html#common

Comment: Thx, I recall it working that way with older versions. I should have clarified - this is version is 2022.2.3. It stores the .xml files in the project root directory under a .run dir. When copied to the .run dir of another workspace, how does one read them in from there? That is what I am unable to figure out.